# Stopwatch functions in jubula

Tags: jubula

I'm a beginner with jubula and i'm stuck with a problem ... I have an application that can load genetics maps and I want to know how much time it takes to do this so I was thinking to use star watch and read watch to do this but I found no way to "print" or get the times stored in the variables of stop watch and start watch ... is it even possible ? if yes can I have an ide how to do this?

ps: I’m currently trying to use “Check numeric values” but it seems that it’s not ok or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Jubula can not do measurements, it can only perform [Functional Tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_testing).

It can only decide whether a function works or not, the results are Successful or Failed.

In my opinion it's the programmer's task to use a library which keeps track of the application's performance. However, you could use the time-out function of Jubula's Test Cases to decide if loading times are acceptable or overwhelming.

(let's say: if you have a loading-dialog with a progress bar, then you can wait for it to close within time-out)

Comment: ha ok ... I'm fixed with this answer, I think I will have to figure out  another strategy (with the closing time-out) because the application is complete and it lacks of JUnit tests ... so to keep track of its performance is just horrible . Thanks for the answer and in such a short time .

Comment: You are welcome! :-) If you run into any problem while implementing your tests, I recommend you raising questions on this site: [sqa.stackexchange.com](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/)